# Performing .replace() on Buffer (Node.js) contents?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is quite a newb question, but I have not found any reliable answers through Google/SO/Etc.

If you have content in a Buffer, what is the best pattern for running a `.replace()` on that content?

Do you simply pull out the content with `.toString()`, run `replace()`, then put it back in the Buffer? Or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: @Gaby Thanks. I usually do that. In a hurry this afternoon. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you want to replace, `Buffers` don't reallocate them self, the `Buffer` object you have in JavaScript is merely a "pointer" into an external memory region (I'm speaking specifically about Node.js 3.x here, the old "SlowBuffers" in 2.x work in a different way).

So there are two possible scenarios:

1. Your replacement value's length is `<>` the value that's being replaced. In this case there's not much you can do, you need to use `toString()` which allocates a new `String` (hint: slow) and then create a new `Buffer` based on the size of that string.
2. You're just swapping bytes (`[]` on buffers is *not* a character index) here it <s>will be way faster</s> would be faster on 2.x to just use a plain loop, and perform the replacement your self, since there is nearly no allocation overhead (Node allocates a new int with the same value as the one that was written) but on 3.x `toString` is fine for 99% of the time.

But what you really want to watch out for is, that you don't write gigantic strings to sockets, because that's **really** slow under 2.x.
Due to the fact that V8 can move the strings in memory at any time,  Node 2.x needs to copy them out before passing their pointer to the OS. This has been fixed with some hacks on V8 in 3.x.

Comment: Actually we're using this in production. So we're still in 2.x

Comment: Then the `toString()` version will be even slower, since the buffer allocation afterwards will take even longer, Buffers in Node 3.x are 10x faster then in 2.x. So if you can go with the `[]` approach. But in the end it all comes down to whether this is performance critical, unless you do this 2000x per request I don't think it will have any impact. Also not that the real bottleneck is when writing strings to sockets in 2.x since they have to be copied out for the kernel to be able to readthem safely. V8 might move them around and therefore invaliding the pointer, thus the copy.