# Javascript Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

In an attempt to add queue type functionality to nodejs's Buffer class, I have constructed the following function:

```
Buffer.prototype.popleft = function(n) {
  tRet = this.slice(0,n);
  this = this.slice(n,this.length-1); // error here
  return tRet;
};
```

however, this code yields the following error:
"ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

I know that the issue is with the assignment of 'this' within the function, what I dont know is better way of accomplishing this same type of logic.

EDIT:

Ended up writing an object around the Buffer as shown below:

```
sPort.vBuffer = {}
sPort.vBuffer.buff = new Buffer(0);
sPort.vBuffer.off = 0;
sPort.vBuffer.expect = -1;

sPort.vBuffer.ReadChr = function() {
    this.off ++;
    return this.buff[this.off - 1];
};

sPort.vBuffer.ReadUInt32LE = function() {
    this.off += 4;
    return this.buff.readUInt32LE(this.off - 4);
}

sPort.vBuffer.ReadInt32LE = function() {
    this.off += 4;
    return this.buff.readInt32LE(this.off - 4);
}

sPort.vBuffer.Write = function(aData) {
    this.buff = Buffer.concat([this.buff.slice(this.off),aData])
    this.off = 0;
};
```

Comment: Try `splice` to mutate the array.

Comment: @elclanrs Is the node.js Buffer a simple array? According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391574/performing-replace-on-buffer-node-js-contents it may not be that simple.

Comment: @elclanrs well the Node `Buffer` prototype doesn't seem to have a `splice`

Comment: Oh, I missed that actually. I don't know then.

Comment: `this` is a reserved word (not a variable) and it *cannot* be used as an identifier or [Reference Specification Type](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7) value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign to `this`. You can assign to a copy of it, but in your case it looks like that won't do any good.

According to the Node documentation, Buffer instances cannot be resized. Now, whether that's because Node simply provides no APIs to do that, or because of some set of internal implementation assumptions/dependencies, I don't know. There sure doesn't look like any way to alter the length of a Buffer instance.

You could use `.copy` to shift the contents, and then fill the last position(s) with some dummy value (`null` or `undefined` I guess).

Comment: I get that I cant modify the buffer, but what I would like to do is take the old_buffer and split it into 2x buffers popleft_buffer which is returned and remains_buffer and change the assignment of this from old_buffer to remains_buffer

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction right, but there's just no good way to do that without exploring the innards of the Buffer code.  Your code here cannot make the Buffer instance be something different than it already is. It can *modify* the Buffer object, but you have to do it by directly manipulating the object (whatever that means; I don't know what the innards look like).